# Export a similarity matrix to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been playing around with surpriselib and I'm trying to build a top-40 movie recommender for a website. How would I be able to convert the similarity matrix to a CSV so that I could build an API for my website? Would there be any other alternatives as it would be slow/inefficient to run the algorithm every time for each user?

**Similarity matrix generation code snippet**

```
from surprise import KNNBaseline

sim_options = {'name': 'cosine', 'user_based': False}
self.simsAlgo = KNNBaseline(sim_options=sim_options)
self.simsAlgo.fit(self.fullTrainSet)
```

**What I've tried**

I tried to create a similarity dataframe using pandas, but there seems to be an issue that I do not understand. Pretty sure this isn't the right approach.

```
import pandas

similarityFile = "similarity.csv"
pandas.DataFrame(self.simsAlgo).to_csv(similarityFile, sep=';')
```

This throws a `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!` error.

```
 File "SVDBakeOff.py", line 31, in <module>
    evaluator = Evaluator(evaluationData, rankings)
  File "/home/nived/Desktop/RecSys-Materials/MatrixFactorization/Evaluator.py", line 15, in __init__
    ed = EvaluationData(dataset, rankings)
  File "/home/nived/Desktop/RecSys-Materials/MatrixFactorization/EvaluationData.py", line 41, in __init__
    self.simsDf = pandas.DataFrame(self.simsAlgo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 485, in __init__
    raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Quite new to all of this, so please do help me!

Comment: in which step you are getting data, so according to that we can give input.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant. I'd like to export this cosine similarity matrix into a CSV or a pickle file so that I could make use of the data.

Comment: I mean does "self.simsAlgo" contains the data that you are trying to export to csv?

Comment: The error can be interpreted as you are giving the wrong format data to pandas data frame function which can't understand your data to create the frame.

Comment: Yes, that was just something that I'd tried. SimsAlgo is of a surpriselib type, so I won't be able to iterate through it/format the data. How would I go about it?

Comment: generally fit function doesn't give output data. either we have o use predict or transform function to get the output. fit is only used for the training of the model.